# Pass all the values of a database table without limit()

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

If i run this code it passes only 6 values of the database.

```
// Begin building the query.
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid'));


  // Fetch the result set.
  $result = $query  -> execute();
```

I know that if i put limit() in my code i will run more values

```
// Begin building the query.
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid'))
    ->limit(2000);

  // Fetch the result set.
  $result = $query  -> execute();
```

but how i can run all the values of the db table without this limit()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `PagerDefault` limit is set to 10. You should be able to pass a parameter like `0`, `NULL` or `FALSE` in order to get all the values from the table.

Try something like this:

```
// Begin building the query.
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid'))
    ->limit(NULL);

  // Fetch the result set.
  $result = $query  -> execute();
```

Or:

```
 // Begin building the query.
      $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
        ->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->orderBy('wid')
        ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid'))
        ->limit(0);

      // Fetch the result set.
      $result = $query  -> execute();
```

Or:

```
// Begin building the query.
      $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
        ->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->orderBy('wid')
        ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid'))
        ->limit(FALSE);

      // Fetch the result set.
      $result = $query  -> execute();
```

Comment: Try not to use the PagerDefault or do a count query first, pass the value to a variable and use it in the PagerDefault->limit :)

Comment: ia m new in drupal and i do not understand nothing about what you say could you write me down that things as code?

Comment: Use a really big number.  Or get rid of the 3rd party software that is getting in the way.